# How do I decode XML in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa

I download a XML file from wikipedia.org/w/api.php.
This file includes some special characters.
When I parse this XML file in Objective C these characters are seperated from the rest.
So how do I decode it **correctly**?

Comment: can you give an example of what the xml downloaded looks like?

Comment: Could you please give us a sample of that XML content, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`NSUTF8StringEncoding`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) might be what you are looking for.  Here is an example that downloads xml data from a url and returns it as UTF8 encoded `NSData`:

```
+ (NSData *)getXML {
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[SOME_URL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]]];
    if (data) {
        NSString *response = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        if (![response isEqualToString:@""]) {
            response = [response stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"&#x26;"];
            data = [response dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            return data;
        }
        [response release], response = nil;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: @Carter The question is so vague, not sure what else he wants... Waiting on a response from the OP to add more.